# How to insert the SO-like <kbd> effect into my HTML-based presentation?

Tags: html, markdown, reveal.js

I am using reveal.js to create an HTML-based presentation. I would like to insert the keyboard symbols like those provided by SO and Github by using the `<kbd>SPACE</kbd>` syntax resulting in this glyph: <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

I have tried using [the `reveal.js` mechanism for inserting Markdown](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#markdown), but to no avail -- the word SPACE  just shows up as regular text. `reveal.js` relies `marked.js` but I could not find anything about this in [its documentation](https://marked.js.org/#/README.md) either. I have a hard time figuring out how SO and Github achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS to style the tag. There's an [article](http://www.jimmyscode.com/css-styling-for-kbd-tags/) on how to style the `kbd` tags just like StackOverflow.

Example:

```css
kbd {
  padding:0.1em 0.6em;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  font-size:11px;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  background-color:#f7f7f7;
  color:#333;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px #ffffff inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px #ffffff inset;
  box-shadow:0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px #ffffff inset;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 0.1em;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
  line-height:1.4;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<kbd>Space</kbd>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is actually much simpler than I thought. The glyphs looked like real icons, not just text with the right style applied.

Comment: For anyone interested in applying this solution within the `reveal.js` framework, I had to add a few additional `!important` modifiers to make these settings overrule those set by reveal.

Comment: I removed the hard-coded `font-size` to make it work as a customization with existing reveal themes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define CSS styles to tell the browser how to display the contents of the `<kdb>` tag. For example, using the `inspect` dev tool of my browser, I can see that SO uses a number of CSS rules to create the border/background color/shadow of the tag.

[image]

Without those CSS rules, the tag would simply display as plain text on SO as well. In fact, using this simple document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
    I would like to insert the keyboard symbols like those provided by
    SO and Github by using the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> syntax resulting in this 
    glyph: <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

We can see that the only "default" styles provided by the browser is setting `font-family: monospace`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize I could inspect the styles in that way in my browser.